# The local variable is not used, although it is being used

Tags: java, android

I am getting the `The value of the local variable dayOfMonthString is not used` inside eclipse, although I am using the variable.

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
{
    String dayOfMonthString; // The value of the local variable dayOfMonthString is not used

    if (dayOfMonth < 10)
    {
        dayOfMonthString = "0" + Integer.toString(dayOfMonth);
    } else
    {
        dayOfMonthString = Integer.toString(dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

Comment: the whole method is useless, you don't use `dayOfMonthString` **value**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only set value to this variable and never use its value. So - it is never used.

Comment: You don't "call" variables. The OP is setting the variable's value but never *using* it.

Answer (score 3):

Until you read a variables value it is referred as unused.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning values to a variable itself is not the same thing as using the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you never used the the value of dayOfMonthString as you only assigned the values to it on the based of conditions but never used in logic so it is saying that it was never used.